# Failed to clone bitbucket repository on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, bitbucket

I'm using an AWS instance to deploy a code, my first step I to clone the code in AWS instance.
The cloning request required me to input password, the password is successfully for login bitbucket website, but when I try to input password for cloning, it failed

```
nabih@aws9-1:~$ git clone https://Nabih_Bawazir@bitbucket.org/company_name/user_service.git
Cloning into 'user_service'...
Password for 'https://Nabih_Bawazir@bitbucket.org':
```

After input password, I am use password that successfully login in bitbucket website, here's the error message

```
remote: Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method.
remote: If you are unsure of which login details or login method to use, visit:
remote: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/log-into-or-connect-to-bitbucket-cloud/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/company_name/user_service.git/'
```

What the possibility beside the wrong password?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbitbucket%5D+remote%3A+Login+failed+due+to+incorrect+login+credentials+or+method