# bad/illegal format or missing URL when deploy from bitbucket repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I following [this instruction](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Authentication-failed-while-cloning-repository-from-bit-bucket/qaq-p/692295) because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76411443/failed-to-clone-bitbucket-repository-on-aws-instance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here's the code

```
nabih@cloudaws-1:~$ git clone https://git@bitbucket.org:company_name/backend_service.git/
```

Here's the output

```
Cloning into 'backend_service'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org:company_name/backend_service.git/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check the URL**: Double-check the URL you provided for the Bitbucket repository. Make sure it is correct and follows the proper format. The correct format should resemble `https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository_name>.git`, so according to this, your URL should be `https://git@bitbucket.org/company_name/backend_service.git` not `https://git@bitbucket.org:company_name/backend_service.git/`

**SSH vs. HTTPS:** Determine whether you should be using SSH or HTTPS to access the repository. If you have set up SSH keys for authentication, make sure you are using the SSH URL instead of the HTTPS URL. The SSH URL format should resemble `git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repository_name>.git`. According to this format your URL changes to `git@bitbucket.org:company_name/backend_service.git`